# How can I configure Vim to work with bitcoin core C++ code and have intellisense like functionality?

Tags: plugin-coc, filetype-c++

I installed Conquer Of Completion (COC) plugin and now I can edit C++ projects with Vim taking advantage of syntax highlighting, autocompletion, inline error messages, etc. But when I try to open bitcoin source code files I get too many errors, like:

`Too many errors emitted, stopping now`
`'wallet/coinselection.h' file not found`
`Unknown type name 'OutputGroup'`
Etc.

Is there a best practice to work with the bitcoin source code in Vim, or at least some general recommendations you can share?

Thanks!

Comment: We would need your code to reproduce the problem. But maybe the message of coc is correct and ther are many warning to report in the source file.

Comment: It’s an open source project https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin code compiles w/o errors

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Which lsp did you install for c++?

Comment: Thanks, Not sure if I installed lsp, what are the options? This is my `coc-settings.json: {   "clangd.path": "~/.config/coc/extensions/coc-clangd-data/install/14.0.0/clangd_14.0.0/bin/clangd" }`

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look probably later today. I suppose you ran `:CocInstall coc-clangd` to install it.

Comment: I have tried but I can't reproduce your problem. I suppose you have to give us more information. i.e. What are the step your follow? What is the exact symptom (a small readable screenshot may help or even a short screencast :-/)

Comment: Thanks. I made a short screencast, https://youtu.be/T8JXtA0XUzM , maybe I configured something wrong. With this update I'm getting the <Tab> mapping warning I have to fix that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138840/discussion-between-vivian-de-smedt-and-bitcoin-1o1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually `clangd` configuration that you have to change.

Create a `.clangd` file in your user folder (`~/.clangd`)

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: -ferror-limit=0
```

The problem has been reported at: [Too many errors emitted, stopping now](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd/issues/255)